# how to count percentage in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I'm currently working on feedback system where the user can give feedback, In my case, I have to count percentage for each option like the question has many options I should show the percentage for each option, For example, how many people selected option a,b,c,d so on.

My Answers table

```
     user_id         question_id      option(selected by user)
     1                       1                             2
     2                       1                             1
     3                       1                             4
     4                       1                             3
```

Now what I want to achieve is

```
  question1
     option1(25% people selected option1)
     option2(25% people selected option2)
     option3(25% people selected option3)
     option4(25% people selected option4)
```

What should be the query for above output,Can any one help on that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

You will get percentage of each option for question with **question_id = 1**

```
DB::table('answers')->where('question_id',1)
    ->select('option',DB::raw('count(*) *100 / (select count(*) from answers) as count'))
    ->groupBy('option')
    ->get();
```

Comment: it says syntax error, unexpected ')' on second line.

Comment: @ManjunathAM I've updated try updated one, there is syntax error before due to typo

Comment: No @Sagar Gautam In updated answer also there is an error,it says SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option) * 100 / (select COUNT(*) from answers) as count from `answers` where `qu' at line 1 (SQL: select `option`, COUNT(option) * 100 / (select COUNT(*) from answers) as count from `answers` where `question_id` = 1 group by `option`)

Comment: @ManjunathAM I think query seems to be correct and I don't know why not woking. I've added curly braces again and updated. Try this one please.

Comment: No @Sagar Gautam this time also it didn't work.again same error  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option) * 100 / (select COUNT(*) from answers)) as count from `answers` where `q' at line 1 (SQL: select `option`, (COUNT(option) * 100 / (select COUNT(*) from answers)) as count from `answers` where `question_id` = 1 group by `option` limit 1)

Comment: @ Manjunath A M can you please share your sql version

Comment: @Manjunath A M and also you can use same query?

Comment: Mysql version is 5.7.18

Comment: @ManjunathAM As error says but I don't thing it's necessory to write COUNT('option') instead of COUNT(option)

Comment: Yes Got it, there was some problem in the second line please take look I've updated your answer, thank you

Comment: Congrats @ManjunathAM

Comment: Great Cheers @ManjunathAM